# How to use sdo_relate covers with Polygon and Point

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, geospatial

I'm trying to find all points that are covered by a polygon on a oracle11g server.
Inside and contains are returning logical values but covers and covered are always false.
Do I misunderstand this? Shouldn't covers be true if contains is true when the point is in the middle of the rectangle polygon?

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE geo
(
    name varchar(255),
    geo  MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY NOT NULL
);
```

Setup meta data

```
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata(table_name, column_name, diminfo, srid)
VALUES (
       'GEO',
       'GEO',
       SDO_DIM_ARRAY(MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('LONGITUDE',-180, 180, 0.25),
                     MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('LATITUDE',-90, 90, 0.25)),
       4326);
```

Create spatial index

```
CREATE INDEX blabla ON geo (geo) INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;
```

Make a rectangle between 0/0 and 2/2

```
INSERT INTO geo (name, geo)
VALUES ('SimplePolygon',
        sdo_geometry(2003, 4326, null,
                     sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 1),
                     sdo_ordinate_array(0, 0,
                                        2, 0,
                                        2, 2,
                                        0, 2,
                                        0, 0)));
```

Put a point on 1/1

```
INSERT INTO geo(name, geo)
VALUES ('SimplePoint',
        sdo_geometry(2001, 4326, null,
                     sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1, 1),
                     sdo_ordinate_array(1, 1)));
```

Related all data with all data and see what mask returns true/false.

```
select
  g1.name, 
  g2.name,
  sdo_relate(g1.geo, g2.geo, 'mask=COVEREDBY') as COVEREDBY,
  sdo_relate(g1.geo, g2.geo, 'mask=COVERS') as COVERS,
  sdo_relate(g1.geo, g2.geo, 'mask=COVERS+INSIDE') as COVERSINSIDE,
  sdo_relate(g1.geo, g2.geo, 'mask=INSIDE') as INSIDE,
  sdo_relate(g1.geo, g2.geo, 'mask=CONTAINS') as CONTAINS,
  sdo_relate(g1.geo, g2.geo, 'mask=ANYINTERACT') as ANYINTERACT,
  -- turn around geometry
  sdo_relate(g2.geo, g1.geo, 'mask=COVEREDBY') as COVEREDBY2,
  sdo_relate(g2.geo, g1.geo, 'mask=COVERS') as COVERS2,
  sdo_relate(g2.geo, g1.geo, 'mask=INSIDE') as INSIDE2,
  sdo_relate(g2.geo, g1.geo, 'mask=CONTAINS') as CONTAINS2,
  sdo_relate(g2.geo, g1.geo, 'mask=ANYINTERACT') as ANYINTERACT2
from geo g1, geo g2
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [Spatial Relationships and Filtering documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/spatial-relationships-and-filtering.htm#SPATL460):

> - `COVERS`: The boundary and interior of one object is completely contained in the interior or the boundary of the other object, their interiors intersect, and the boundary or the interior of one object and the boundary of the other object intersect.
> - `COVEREDBY`: The opposite of `COVERS`. `A COVEREDBY B` implies `B COVERS A`.
>
> [image: Topological Relationships]

The reason why the relationship is false is the final condition that "and the boundary or the interior of one object and the boundary of the other object intersect." Since your point and rectangle to not have boundaries that intersects then they neither `COVER` nor are `COVEREDBY` one and other.

Comment: I put the point on the border of the polygon but covers does not return TRUE. If I do this with another polygon that is partially on the line of the bigger polygon then COVERS returns TRUE for the two polygons. Can it be that points are not compatible with COVERS.